# A way to double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

Consider the following problem $$\int_{\sqrt{b^2-\frac{a^2}{2}}}^{\frac{a}{2}} \int_{\sqrt{b^2-\frac{a^2}{4}x^2}}^{\frac{a}{2}}\,\, \frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2-x^2-y^2}} dy\, dx$$ My first thought was that polar coordinate can be used but it does not work out.  Any ideas. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you at least compute the inner integral ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, for I was trying to use polar coordinate but I think it does not work. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Where is this problem coming from? Why would you think that polar coordinates would work better?

Comment: @Andrei, Maybe this is one of the ways that I usually use double integral. Do you recommend a way to do it ?

Comment: I am trying to visualize the domain. @00GB would you also do polar coordinates if the lower limits would both be $0$?

Comment: @Andrei, lower limits are not zero .

Comment: Before attempting the integral I was trying to work out the allowable ranges for $a$ and $b$ for the integral to be real-valued which resulted in an enormous amount of complicated case work. Are there any specific ranges you're primarily interested in that would make such casework unnecessary?

Comment: @DavidH, lets say $a$ and $b$ between $0$ and $1$

Comment: @00GB OK. Presumably you also want $\sqrt{b^2-\frac{a^2}{2}}<\frac{a}{2}$ in order for the $x$ integral to be over a normal interval. But it turns out that $\frac{a}{2}<\sqrt{b^2-\frac{a^2}{4}x^2}$ for all $x$ in that interval, which is a problem for the limits of the integral over $y$....